# ESP32 invalid segment length 0x15abba12 when doing Update.writeStream()

Tags: arduino, updates, esp32, firmware, ota

I recently had to downsize my ESP32 WROVER package down to 8MB from 16MB before, due to component unavailability.

This broke my update process, showing the `invalid segment length 0x15abba12` error message while doing `Update.writeStream()`.

I wrote my new 8MB partition as follows (I use FFAT):

```
# Name,   Type, SubType, Offset,  Size, Flags
nvs,        data,    nvs,   0x9000,     0x5000,
otadata,    data,    ota,   0xE000,     0x2000, 
app0,       app,    ota_0,  0x10000,    0x2A0000,   
app1,       app,    ota_1,  0x2B0000,   0x2A0000,   
ffat,       data,    fat,   0x550000,   0x2B0000,
```

My firmware.bin size is 1.4MB (1411248, or 0x1588B0).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Weird enough. It appears that the firmware.bin produced as usually by platformio had some issues, hence the segment fault.
By simply recompiling and linking again, the produced firmware.bin was OK and the update completed successfully.

=> So if you face similar segment fault issue, try to rebuild your firmware bin file before loosing time to debug your actually working code.